# Is there a 3rd party google maps API for iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, mapkit

I need to remove mapkit from my iOS app but still need google maps.  In this particular instance I merely need satellite views that are zoomable and scrollable. Markers would be nice, but not required.

I can use a webview with javascript, but I'd prefer a mapkit-like API so I can simply transition away from mapkit without significant effort.

Are there third party google map APIs I can use that allow me to use google maps on iOS devices without invoking Apple's built in mapping API?

Comment: There are no third party APIs that integrate Google Maps with iOS.  If you need to remove MapKit from your application, you could use the Google Maps JavaScript API in a WebView.  That would give you access to Google's data, without the need to load MapKit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google released their new Maps SDK for iOS yesterday. It can be found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/

Comment: Be careful to read the licence first to make sure you can use it for what you want to do:  https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an alternative library, there are a few:

- [RouteMe](https://github.com/route-me/route-me) which is open source and supports multiple map sources.
- [MapBox](http://mapbox.com/mobile/) is a third party service with an iOS SDK

Comment: Unfortunately RouteMe doesn't support Google as a map source, and in this case I need to use Google imagery.

Comment: Apologies, I missed that bit about your post. You could obtain a Google Maps API Key and then write a RouteMe Source file for Google Maps. It doesn't look too complex and the only thing i'd be wary of is ensuring that your app still follows Google's Maps API rules

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps terms of service specifically [prevents direct tile access](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos_tiles). You will not be able to legally use Google Maps tiles on iOS outside of MapKit.